# Large app size in AppStore. Is it allowed to download external assets?

Tags: ios, app-store, haxe, openfl

I've developed a game, it's total file-size with all assets is about 220Mb.

The game is developed in Haxe language with a framework called openFL - that allows to compile iOS and Android versions from a single source.

Because Android's Google Play doesn't allow apps larger than 50Mb in one go, I've separated the graphics assets and sounds from the code, leaving the app at about 1.5 Mb. I don't want to make a separate branch for iOS, so I'd like to use the same logic for App Store as well.

My question is - is it allowed to download the external assets for iOS similar to how Google play does it? Will App Store host these files for me?

Comment: You need to keep your assets in your server and you can download the assets from your application. It is allowed. Appstore won't host your assets.

Comment: Also, make sure that your downloaded assets are correctly flagged not to be backed up. There are numerous cases listed here on SO of app rejection because apps download significant assets that are then flagged to be backed up to iCloud.

Comment: Thank you both for the info, can't wait to try it out

Comment: And please, someone answer the question/author selfanswer it, so it will be marked as answered.